# Konjunktion "dass"

Tags: conjunction

Es gibt ja verschiedene Konjunktionen (temporale, konzessive, konditionale usw.). Hat die deutsche Konjunktion *dass*, die einen Ergänzungssatz einleitet, einen "Namen"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bezeichnungen wie *temporal, konzessiv, konditional* bezeichnen nie ein Wort oder eine Wortart, sondern dienen dazu, Konnektoren nach ihrer Bedeutung einzuteilen. *Konnektor* ist ein Begriff quer zu den Wortarten: Es geht um Wörter, die Sätze in eine bestimmte semantische Beziehung zueinander setzen.*

> Sie ißt kein Fleisch. Sie ist **nämlich** Vegetarierin.
>   Sie ißt kein Fleisch, **weil** sie Vegetarierin ist.
>   Sie ißt kein Fleisch, **denn** sie ist Vegetarierin.

Hier liegen drei unterschiedliche Wortarten vor: ein Adverb, ein Subjunktor und der Einzelgänger *denn*. Aber in allen drei Fällen wird eine Verbindung zwischen zwei Sätzen hergestellt, so daß der zweite Satz die Begründung für den ersten darstellt. Es handelt sich also um *kausale Konnektoren*.

Wenn der Subjunktor *daß* einen Subjekt- oder Objektsatz einleitet, trägt er nichts zur Bedeutung bei und kann deshalb nicht auf diese Weise klassifiziert werden. Zur Bezeichnung bleibt nur die Wortart: Subjunktor oder subordinierende Konjunktion.

Es gibt aber auch Fälle, in denen *daß* ein Konnektor ist, also einen Beitrag zur Bedeutung leistet, nämlich wenn es Adverbialsätze wie die folgenden einleitet:

> Er log, daß sich die Balken bogen. (konsekutiv)
>   Ich bring dir mal ein Kissen, daß du bequemer liegst. (final)

<sub>* Vielleicht kann man den Begriff *Konnektor* mit einem wie *temporaler Ausdruck* vergleichen. Diese teilen sich die Bedeutung, gehören aber verschiedenen Kategorien an: *gestern, montags* (Adverbien), *täglich, diesjährig* (Adjektive), *jeden Monat* (adverbialer Akkusativ), *am Montag, im Winter* (Präpositionalphrasen).</sub>

Comment: Aber mit dem "daß" bist du eisern - oder?

Comment: Bei uns hiess das in der 3. Klasse  "dass-Satz" und somit wussten alle, dass man das mit 2 s schreibt (das Doppel-s finde ich auf meiner Tastatur nicht).
Offenbar haben nicht nur Schulkinder heute mit der  Grammatik Terminologie ihre liebe Mühe, so dass man das dass, das das und das das kaum noch richtig geschrieben findet (gemeint ist Konjunktion, relative Pronomen und Artikel)